# C: TCP send memory page

Tags: c, sockets

I created a memory page using mmap on my server. I'd like to send the data inside that memory page to the client.

Is it possible with tcp socket?

Answer (score 0):

Use `send` function to do this.

```
ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

After creating the memory page using the `mmap` you will get the void pointer, use that pointer to send the message to the client.